# C++ forward declarations with multiple classes, derived class

Tags: c++, derived-class, forward-declaration

Currently I have 3 classes, set up like this:

World.h

```
include "WorldObject.h"
class WorldObject;
class TextObject; // when this is added, compiles fine, but tobj is incomplete when accessed 
//(world->tobj->function()).  if #include "TextObject.h" is added, numerous errors occur within TextObject.h
class World { 
public:
      WorldObject* wobj; // works fine
      TextObject* tobj; //trying to get this to be functional
};
```

WorldObject.h

```
#include "World.h"
class World;
class WorldObject {
public:
      WorldObject(World* world){...} // works fine, world can be accessed from world objects
};
```

TextObject.h

```
#include "WorldObject.h"
#include "World.h"
class TextObject : WorldObject {
public:
      TextObject(World* world) : WorldObject(w){...};
};
```

How can I use forward declaration so that tobj will be accessible from World.h, as obj is, with no errors?  I am also using #pragma once at the beginning of each class.  I have attempted to add "class World" to TextObject.h and "class TextObject" to World.h, but none of the seemingly standard procedures are working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try to add `#include "TextObject.h"` in World.h and at the same time add `class World;` in TextObject.h If you get errors, what exactly are they?

Comment: `#include <WorldObject.h>` in your .cpp file rather than your header and you can access it from there. Your header includes are causing circular dependencies, which you avoid through forward declarations.

Comment: @Kai that fixed it!! Such a stupid mistake haha.  If you want you can post it as an answer and I will mark correct.  thx so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <WorldObject.h>` in your `.cpp` file rather than your header and you can access it from there.

Your header includes are causing circular dependencies, which you avoid through forward declarations.